# /bin/sh: 1 : conda: not found error when executing a conda run command through a nodejs script using pm2

Tags: python, node.js, bash, conda, pm2

## Introduction

I am running a nodejs server in the production environment using pm2. The javascript file a python script upon a prompt using the `conda run` method. This command errors out with the following message: `/bin/sh: 1: conda: not found`. However, running the same js file using `npx nodemon` or simply `node` works well without any errors.

## Detailed Description

The javascript file is as follows

```
...
command = "conda run -n p2vois python  path_to_python_script_file.py "+variable_with_arguments_for_the_python_script;
...
var pyProcess = cmd.get(command,
                (err, datax, stderr)=> {
                        console.log("here datax: %s", datax)
                        if(err){
                            console.log("python script cmd error: " + err)
                        }
                        else{
                            ...
                        }
```

This code upon running using the `sudo pm2 start server.js` command gives an error as follows:

```
python script cmd error: Error: Command failed: conda run -n p2vois python path_to_python_script_file.py arguments_for_the_python_script
/bin/sh: 1: conda: not found
```

However, running the same javascript file server.js with `npx nodemon` or `node` does not give any error.

## Possible causes of error

I believe the cause should be conda trying to run the command through `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash`. Another reason could be an underlying path issue while running with `pm2`. I do not know how to fix this error, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the case of using `sudo`? Don't use it unless you need to have super user privilege.

Comment: Yes @kj-crypto removing the sudo privilege worked. Thanks.

Comment: On my Linux 18.04 system I got failure with `sudo conda ...` despite having su-priveleges. Just `conda ...` was successful.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

Just removed the `sudo` privilege for the pm2 command and the code started working again.